# Is there a where condition to compare the value of the string after splitting?

Tags: sql, hana

**Database：SAP HANA**

**First table is original data.**

Original

| MATNR | EAU | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 1 |
| 1 | 30 | 50 |
| 2 | 70 | 1 |
| 2 | 70 | 50 |
| 2 | 70 | 100 |
| 3 | 10 | 1 |

**Second table is output after group by.**

Output ( Group by MATNR )

| MATNR | EAU | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 1, 50 |
| 2 | 70 | 1, 50, 100 |
| 3 | 10 | 1 |

**Third table is the expected result.**

Output ( Where EAU > second QTY )

| MATNR | EAU | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 70 | 1, 50, 100 |

Is there a sql like `WHERE SPLIT(QTY, ', ')[1] > EAU` ?

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? (Remove the other dbms tags.)

Comment: Also, don't post images of text; text should be provided as `text` (seems a silly thing to say when you say it, right?!).

Comment: The question remains. which dbms are you using? (`split` is a product specific function.)

Comment: It's my first question, sorry about post images of text. I'm using SAP HANA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what database you are using, but one method would use `row_number()`:

```
select matnr, eau,
       listagg(qty, ', ') within group (order by qty)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by matnr order by qty) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by matnr, eau
having eau > sum(case when seqnum = 2 then qty end) ;
```

Note:  This uses generic SQL.  The exact syntax (particularly for the string aggregation) depends on the database you are using.

Comment: Excellent ! ROW_NUMBER() sovled my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.

- In a DBMS that supports arrays, you can use `ARRAY_AGG` in the `HAVING` clause to pull out

```sql
SELECT
  t.MATNR,
  t.EAU,
  STRING_AGG(t.QTY, ',')
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.MATNR,
  t.EAU
HAVING t.EAU > ARRAY_AGG(t.QTY ORDER BY t.QTY)[2];
```

- You could use a row-numbering solution

```sql
SELECT
  t.MATNR,
  t.EAU,
  STRING_AGG(t.QTY, ',')
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.MATNR, t.EAU ORDER BY t.QTY) AS rn
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY
  t.MATNR,
  t.EAU
HAVING t.EAU > SUM(CASE WHEN t.rn = 2 THEN t.QTY END);
```

Comment: Excellent ! ROW_NUMBER() sovled my problem.